# Alternative proof of de l'Hospital theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, alternative-proof

I see that the usual proof of de l'Hospital theorem involves the mean value theorem and is carried on in a case-by-case fashion.

Could you point out some other proofs of de l'Hospital that are impressive because of their subtlety and elegance?

Comment: We really need the mean value theorem since the differences $f(x)−f(a)$ and $g(x)−g(a)$ are related to derivatives via the MVT.